# Objective-C Mantle Paging

Tags: ios, objective-c, github-mantle

I am using [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) in my objective-c application, and able to fetch and display data. However, I am not able to figure out how to implement paging/pagination using Mantle. If I fetch data again, it over writes my previously fetched array. Anyone done this before?